# traversing binary search tree C++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a programming assignment and writing a bunch of functions to implement a binary search tree, and some functions are given. I thought I understood recursion, but I keep getting hung up on switching directions, if you will.

Here is a function given with the assignment:

```
static void deleteAll(BSTNode<Data>* n) {
  if (0 == n) return;
  deleteAll(n->left);
  deleteAll(n->right);
  delete n;
}
```

To delete a really short tree,

```
    root
   /    \
lefty  righty
```

I call `deleteAll(root)`. `n != 0` so now I call `deleteAll(lefty)`. `n != 0` so I call `deleteAll(lefty->left)`. There is no left node of course. When I added the lefty node my constructor initialized the left, right, and parent pointers to 0, so now `n == 0`. So I return out of the function and never delete righty. How do I ever get to `deleteAll(n->right)`?

As I said, this function is provided so I'm not supposed to change it. I thought maybe I have to call `deleteAll(b.begin())` or `b.end()` to start with either the left- or rightmost node, but every time I go through it in my mind I hit `n == 0`.

Please help me understand.

Comment: Maybe make it print in each function at various points so you can follow what happens :) It looks like it should be working correctly from the current code!

Comment: Tell your teacher that the letter n is reserved for sizes. On second thought, don't. Just remember it. That "if(0==n)" threw me off for a sec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine an arrow pointing to the current line that is being executed. When we call `deleteAll(root)`, first we check if `root` is 0:

```
--> if (0 == root) return;
    deleteAll(root->left);
    deleteAll(root->right);
    delete root;
```

Because `root != 0`, we then call `deleteAll(root->left)`:

```
    if (0 == root) return;
--> deleteAll(root->left); /*
    |-1-> if (0 == lefty) return;
    |-2-> deleteAll(lefty->left);
    |-3-> deleteAll(lefty->right);
    |-4-> delete lefty; */
    deleteAll(root->right);
    delete root;
  }
```

Now the arrow will move back up to the top of the function and start doing the same for `lefty`, running through the lines 1-4 in my comment (at line 2, the same expansion will happen again, until a null node is found). But the important thing here is that it *remembers* where it was before the function call so that it can resume later. So `deleteAll(root->left)` will go and do what it does and eventually returns. Then the original call continues:

```
    if (0 == root) return;
    deleteAll(root->left);
--> deleteAll(root->right);
    delete root;
```

Now the right node is deleted too. This happens at every step of the recursion. Remember that `return` only returns out of the current function, not the entire recursive chain.

Answer (score 2):

The return only returns to the function that called it. In the case the `deleteAll(lefty)` (if I understand correct, either that or `deleteAll(root)`). `deleteAll(n->right)` will get called after `deleteAll(n->left)` returns. The post condition of deleteAll is that n and all it's children will be deleted.

Imagine we have the following tree:

```
    a
   / \
   b c
  /   \
 d     e
```

The call graph will be as follows:

```
deleteAll(a)
    deleteAll(a->left)
        deleteAll(a->left->left)
            deleteAll(a->left->left->left)
            deleteAll(a->left->left->right)
        deleteAll(a->left->right)
    deleteAll(a->right)
        deleteAll(a->right->left)
        deleteAll(a->right->right)
            deleteAll(a->right->right->left)
            deleteAll(a->right->right->right)
```

Or in terms of the node names:

```
deleteAll(a)
    deleteAll(b)
        deleteAll(d)
            deleteAll(NULL)
            deleteAll(NULL)
        deleteAll(NULL)
    deleteAll(c)
        deleteAll(NULL)
        deleteAll(e)
            deleteAll(NULL)
            deleteAll(NULL)
```

Comment: @MooingDuck Wow, thanks for that catch. Wow did I ever mess that up the first time through.